# Submit Ajaxform on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange, ajaxform

I have an Ajax form that I need to submit as soon as the user selects an image. The problem is that the form is not submitting. Please any guidance will be appreciated

--The form ---

```
<form id="bgimageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
    <div class="uploadFile timelineUploadBG">
        <input type="hidden" name = "bkg" value = "1"/>
        <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="bgphotoimg" class="custom-file-input">

    </div>

</form>
```

--- The JS Codes ---

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
  $('body').on('change','#bgphotoimg', function() {

    $("#bgimageform").ajaxForm({target:'#timelineBackground'}).submit();

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using Dropzone.js? By default, once the item is added it will 'submit'. You can also drag and drop the image

Comment: No i havent, please do you have a link where I can find it?

Comment: Searching dropzone.js should find it, but regardless: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Thanks checking it out  now

Comment: There is a syntax error. The JSON object passed to `ajaxForm` has a dangling comma.

Try doing:

    `$('#bgimageform').ajaxForm({target:'#timelineBackground'}).submit();`

Comment: I have removed the hanging comma without success

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that first attempt was way off.

Anyways, I've run some tests, and it seems if you do this, it works.

```
$('body').on('change','#bgphotoimg', function() {
    alert("It should have submitted.");
});
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it. http://jsfiddle.net/gt9e160f/

So I would have to point toward your method of submit, because the on change is definitely being called.

I've never used jquery.form.js before, but from their docs I've pulled this:

```
$(function(){

    //bind the form's submit to ajaxForm
    $("body").on('submit', '#bgimageform', function(e){
        $(this).ajaxForm({target:'#timelineBackground'});
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
    $('body').on('change','#bgphotoimg', function() {
        //submit the form
        $("#bgimageform").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: The alert function works, but the submission of the form is the problem.. If if I put the alert function after this line,
$('#bgimageform').ajaxForm({target:'#timelineBackground'}).submit();   it does not work. There is weird about that line..

Comment: One more edit, hopefully this works. Otherwise I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: If you use your browsers debugging tools, see if the submit request is even being made. If it is, double check your server side PHP. In any case, it would be helpful for you to update your answer with any errors or where in the chain it gets broken exactly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gt9e160f/3/  I've verified the form is infact posting. You may need to take an alternate route for images/files vs text

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("body").on('change','input#bgphotoimg', function() {
   $('#bgimageform').submit(AjaxCall);
});
function AjaxCall(){
  // ajax call here 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        // code here 
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
  return false; 
 }
```